# libgdx bullet example

Tags: java, libgdx

I try run this code
http://tinfig.com/git/gdx-bullet-demos/

In Windows it does not work and crashes with an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library: 'gdx-bullet' for target Windows 7, 32-bit
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:151)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet.init(Bullet.java:26)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.demo.screens.SimulationScreen.<clinit>(SimulationScreen.java:38)
```

At Android working fine.

How fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look if you can see gdx-bullet.dll, put it in the current dir, and start the jvm with this parameter -Djava.library.path="."